# Show that these matrices are congruent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic$\ne 2$ and $u$ be an invertible element of $K$.

Show that $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}u&0\\0&-u\end{pmatrix}$ are [congruent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence).

I tried to find a suitable transition matrix but I'm stuck, any ideas please?

Comment: congruent? I think you mean similar... ?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik No, I mean congruent.

Comment: What do you mean by congruent?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick I add a wikipedia link. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it with $K=\mathbb R$?

Comment: Hint: what you're after is the square root of $u$. You should consider the characteristic $\infty$ and the characteristic finite, $\not =2$ separately..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the matrix

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{u+1}{2}& \frac{u-1}{2}\\
\frac{u-1}{2}& \frac{u+1}{2}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: $$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{u + 1}2 & \frac{u - 1}2 \\ \frac{u - 1}2 & \frac{u + 1}2\end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} u & 0 \\ 0 & -u \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{u + 1}2 & \frac{u - 1}2 \\ \frac{u - 1}2 & \frac{u + 1}2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} u^2 & 0 \\ 0 & -u^2\end{bmatrix} \ne \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Try $A^T\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\\\end{pmatrix}A$

Answer (score 3):

As a path towards Rene's answer: Pick some matrix $A$ with unknown coefficients and substitute this into the conjugacy definition. This will give you three constraints, from which you can persuade yourself that it's enough to find the two upper elements. To solve the last equation left, what's a factorization of $u$ that always exists?

Comment: well how do you think I found it in the first place ?

Comment: It being obvious to you doesn't make it obvious to the asker. -@ReneSchipperus

Comment: It wasnt obvious to me, I had to work it out.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: I meant the route to it, not the matrix itself.

Answer (score 0):

If $u^{1/2}$ [exists](http://cap-lore.com/MathPhys/Field/finite/sqrt.html) (e.g. $u \in \mathbb{R}$) and $(u^{1/2})^2=u$ then you can take $P = u^{1/2} I_2$, so that
$$P^T\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix} P= u^{1/2}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}u^{1/2}= \begin{pmatrix}u&0\\0&-u\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Why does $u^{1/2}$ exist? Oh I overlooked the "positive" ... the question is about a general field.